# Optimize database structure for hierarchical settings

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `database`(`MySQL`) structure that I want to optimize.

We sell different products to our clients, the product's settings are stored in a table called `ProductsSettings`

In this table, we store the default settings of each products(`productNumber` starting with P_), each client accounts(`productNumber` starting with A_), and each individual license settings(`productNumber` starting with L_).

```
ProductsSettings
id       productNumber     date     accountId   setting1   setting2   etc
1        P_021545          XXX      1           10         60         ...
2        P_020455          XXX      1           10         60         ...
3        A_025225          XXX      12          30         20         ...
4        A_021345          XXX      13          NULL       NULL       ...
5        L_014445          XXX      24          20         50         ...
6        L_545545          XXX      77          NULL       NULL       ...
7        L_777545          XXX      50          NULL       NULL       ...
```

The customer's admin user can change the settings at account level, and license level.

When a user login to a product, we run a query that first check if a setting is set at license level (`IS NOT NULL`), if not, we look at account level, if not, we take the default setting at product level.

So, the hierarchy is in this order:

```
1 - Product Level

2 - Account Level

3 - License Level
```

Is there another way to store this kind of data, that is more clean and easy to maintain?

Comment: Why, what's wrong with the current structure?

Comment: At the very least, "product number" and "access level" could be in different columns.